# Referencing 3 variables using a for loop and i

Tags: java, variables, for-loop, switch-statement

Is it possible to have three predefined variables:

```
int randomNum1 = 5;
int randomNum2 = 4;
int randomNum3 = 3;
```

and then call these variables by using a for loop as such:

```
for(int i = 1; i < 4; i++){
switch(randomNumi){
...
}
```

Where each time the for loop runs it calls each of the randomNum variables?

Comment: And how do you expect to "call" a variable? Your question does not really make any sense. So, what about you backtrack and explain what the problem is?

Comment: You mean you want `randomNumi` to be `randomNum1`, `randomNum2` or `randomNum3`? Use an [array](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html).

Comment: @fge I would like the switch statement to first call `randomNum1`, then `randomNum2`, then `randomNum3`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try defining array:

```
int randomNum[] = {5, 4, 3};

for(int i = 0; i < randomNum.length; i++){
    switch(randomNum[i]){
       case:......
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, thanks. Our class hasn't covered arrays yet and I was trying to think of a solution that had the same concepts but didn't actually use them.

Comment: No you have three different variables. and you cant have like switch(randomNumi) else compiler wont be happy with it and will say randonNum1 is undefined.